# Loop through html table and display one td column using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Having a small issues in html table - Need to display (which is display:none initially) on click of a button using jquery.

in View

```
<table id="tblLayout" style ="width:100%"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:200px"></th>
                    <th style="width:100px">col1</th>
                    <th style="width:100px">col2</th>
                    <th style="width:500px">col3</th>
                    <th style="width:100px">col4</th>
                    <th style="width:100px">col5</th>
                    <th style="width:1200px">col6</th>                        
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
```

```
@{

        foreach (S.Libs.SAapp in @Model._salist)
        {
           if (blockNo != @app.BlockNo && var_i == 0)
            {
            </td></tr>

                blockNo = @app.BlockNo;
                EndRow = @app.count+ 1;
                <th rowspan ="@EndRow">S<br />T<br />A<br />L<br />L<br />S <br /><br /> @app.StallNo <br />TO <br />@app.End_row</th>
            }

                    <tr>               
                            <td  align="center">@app.col1</td>               
                            <td  align="center"  >@app.col2</td> 
                            <td>@app.col3</td>
                            <td  align="center" >@app.col4</td>
                            <td  align="center" >@app.col5</td>
                            <td>@app.col6</td>                                                                        
                            <td id="chk_edit"> <input type ="checkbox" style="display:none"/> </td>
                            <td> 
                            <input id="hdnId1" value="@app.Id1" type="hidden"/>
                            <input id="hdnId2" value="@app.Id2" type="hidden"/>
                            <input id="hdnId3" value="@app.Id3" type="hidden"/>
                            </td>
                    </tr>                                                     
        }


    }
```

There is a button

```
 <a href="#" class="abut" id="btnEdit"><span class="abut-edit">&nbsp;</span>Edit</a>
```

In JavaScript - I need to enable (or make visible) column 7 in html which is

```
<td id="chk_edit">
```

Not sure how to do this. And also get the td columns that are checked.
How to achieve this?
Help appreciated. Thanks IN Advance

Comment: try $('#btnEdit').on("click",function(){
   $("#chk_edit").show();
});. Example : https://jsfiddle.net/7bLwu1ub/

Comment: Hi.. It enabled only the first row in html table. I have many rows in the table. Basically it should iterate and  display in all rows? Please help

Comment: to display all hidden data rows : $('#btnEdit').on("click",function(){
   $("#tblLayout tr td").show();
});

Comment: Change `id="chk_edit"` (its invalid html to have duplicate `id` attributes) to `class="chk_edit"` and use `$('.chk_edit').show();` - but apply the class to the checkbox not the `td` element (or make the `td` element hidden instead of the checkbox)

Comment: Thanks guys that worked..But now need to get the value of col1 of selected rows . How to get that? also I need to restrict user to select only two rows. Please help with these.. Please :-)

Comment: @user_rhee, Ask a new question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the `click` even on the link, get to the seventh td and show the hidden input.

```
$(function(){

  $("#btnEdit").click(function(e){

     e.preventDefault();

     $("#tblLayout tr").each(function(a,b)  //loop through each tr's
     {    
         //find the 7th td and find the checkbox inside that and show   
         $(b).find("td").eq(6).find("input[type='checkbox']").show();                      
     });        
  });

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/virujodime/edit?html,css,js,output) is a working sample.

A better solution is to update your HTML markup to include a css class to the checkboxes so that we can use that as our jQuery selector and avoid the looping we did above. Also to associate a unique row id/record value for the checkbox, you do not need to keep that in a seperate hidden field. you can store it in html5 data attribute on the checkboxes.

Also, you should not have duplicate Id's for elements. So remove that as well from your loop.

So your new markup will look like

```
<td>@app.col6</td>                                                                        
<td> 
    <input type ="checkbox" class="editChk" data-rowid="@app.Id1" style="display:none"/> 
</td>
```

Now with our new css class selector, showing the checkboxes are easy.

```
$("#btnEdit").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("input.editChk").show();        
});
```

And to get the ids(we stored in data attribute) of the rows with selected checkboxes will be

```
$("#saveBtn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

      var checkedItems= $("input.editChk:checked");
      checkedItems.each(function(a,b){
         var rowId=$(this).data("rowid");
         alert(rowId);
      });

      // OR USE jQuery Map and get an array of Ids
      var idArray = checkedItems.map(function(){
        return $(this).data("rowid");
      }).get();

      console.log(idArray);
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/kiyuyolavu/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample of that.

Comment: Hi.. sorry didnt get that   please see what I am trying to do now  $("tbody tr").each(function () {
                  if ($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked"))              
sessionId = $('#hdnSessionId').val();  meetingId = $('#hdnMeetingId').val();
                                                from_lineno = $('#hdnLineNo').val();
                                            }
                  }
              });

Comment: Sorry ! I do not know what you meant by **didn't get that**

Comment: but this is only giving me first selected  row value..of "hdbLineNo". How to get the next selected row

Comment: I did not understand what you have mentioned in the code. Sorry

Comment: Your original question was hot to display the hidden checkbox on the link click and my answer was for that. It does it for all the rows. Take a look at the working sample link i posted.

Comment: @user_rhee I added some comments to the code which will explain it.

Comment: Thanks, I got it sorry about the previous comment. The columns are getting visible now..gr8. But please any help with the  other query.. how to get the values of selected rows?

Comment: what is the value of a row ? on what event you want the selected rows ?

Comment: on another button click event. I want to get the value of hidden column "hdnId1" . There will only be two rows selected always, so need to get the value of "hdnId1" for first selected row and value of "hdnId1" for second selected row. TIA

Comment: Hi.. any help for the above? please

Comment: @user_rhee I updated the answer with a better solution. Take a look.

Comment: Thankyou very much.. It is working perfectly. Really appreciate the help